# Check dropdown options and do something while typing in input text box

Tags: jquery

Having trouble with this function. I can only make it work for the last dropdown option in select box. In other words, it only does what it's supposed to do if I type the text of the last option in select box. It doesn't recognize that I typed the other options. I do an alert in the each loop and it shows me all the options, and i also alert what i type in. It should work for all the options, but it's not. Trying to add or remove class on the text input box. If i type one of the options add error class. If i change what i type and it doesn't match any of the options, remove error class.

HTML:

```
<select id="select" class="select selectpicker input-block-level" name="select">
    <option value="">pick a thing</option>
    <option value="0.00">#1 thing</option>
    <option value="0.01">1x1 thing</option>
    <option value="0.02">some thing</option>
    <option value="0.03">something</option>
    <option value="0.04">thing</option>
</select>

<input id="text" class="span12" type="text" placeholder="type a thing" value="" name="text">
```

JS:

```
function getValue() {
    var theValue = $('#text').val();
    //alert(theValue);

    //begin tried and failed stuff
    //var exists = 0 != $('#select option[text='+thevalue+']').length;
    //if($('#select option[text='+thevalue+']').length > 0)
    //if(exists == true)
    //{
        //alert("exists");
        //$("#text").addClass("error");
    //} else {
        //$("#text").removeClass("error");
    //}
    //end tried and failed stuff

    $('#select option').each(function(){
        var theDropValue = this.text.toLowerCase();
        //alert (theDropValue);
        var theNewValue = theValue.toLowerCase();
        if (theDropValue == theNewValue) {
            //exists = true;
            $("#text").addClass("error");
        } else {
            $("#text").removeClass("error");
        }
    });
}

$(document.body).on( "change keyup input", "#text", function() {
    getValue();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you only see the last one is because you never break out of the each loop. Once you find the value you need to `return false;` so you stop checking against other values in the loop.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3swv31px/

```
function getValue() {
    var theValue = $('#text').val();
    $('#select option').each(function () {
        var theDropValue = this.text.toLowerCase();
        //alert (theDropValue);
        var theNewValue = theValue.toLowerCase();
        if (theDropValue == theNewValue) {
            //exists = true;
            $("#text").addClass("error");
            return false;
        } else {
            $("#text").removeClass("error");
        }
    });
}

$(document.body).on("change keyup input", "#text", function () {
    getValue();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop, if the value exists, add `error` class and return

```
            if (theDropValue == theNewValue) {
                //exists = true;
                $("#text").addClass("error");
                return; // add this line
            } else {
                $("#text").removeClass("error");
            }
```

Comment: return will not break out of an each loop. You must return false. return will only return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

that's because

> ```
> $('#select option').each
> ```

loops all the items in the object and you have just 1 output that you override each time.

You see just last item working because last item override all the others.